# how to remove table td from return data using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying the feature "Export to Excel", here is my funtion:

```
$scope.OpenigStockexportToExcel = function () {
    debugger
    var data = CreateTableView($scope.GetOpeningStockDetailsReport, 'table', true);
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "OpeningStockDetailsReport.xls");
}
```

The result obtained is the following:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th scope="col">Date</th><th scope="col">Location</th><th scope="col">VNo</th><th scope="col">ProductName</th><th scope="col">UOMName</th><th scope="col">Qty</th><th scope="col">Cost</th><th scope="col">Amount</th><th scope="col">SumQty</th><th scope="col">SumAmount</th><th scope="col">$$hashKey</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="alertnate"><td>10-11-2015</td><td>Dist</td><td>OS33</td><td>Priority</td><td>No's</td><td>4</td><td>2.5</td><td>10</td><td>68</td><td>302</td><td>OS49</td><td>Test 13</td><td>No's</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>25</td><td>68</td><td>302</td><td>object:303</td></tr><tr><td>18-11-2015</td><td>hari</td><td>OS50</td><td>Test 133d</td><td>No's</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>9</td><td>68</td><td>302</td><td>object:304</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to remove the following elements:

```
<th scope="col">$$hashKey</th>
```

...and:

```
<td>object:303<td>
```

value..

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$$hashkey` from your object before passing to generate table.

Like

```
$scope.OpenigStockexportToExcel = function () {
    debugger
    // Delete hash key here from $scope.GetOpeningStockDetailsReport
    delete $scope.GetOpeningStockDetailsReport.$$hashKey;
    var data = CreateTableView($scope.GetOpeningStockDetailsReport, 'table', true);
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "OpeningStockDetailsReport.xls");
}
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Here I remove three Column     delete $scope.GetOpeningStockDetailsReport.$$hashkey;
        delete $scope.GetOpeningStockDetailsReport.SumAmount;
        delete $scope.GetOpeningStockDetailsReport.SumQty;

Comment: It should work. log final object before passing and check it's removed from that. I assume it's object only. Create fiddle to get resolve it faster.

Comment: If i Try in Console..Value will be deleted..But it's in Object

Comment: try to copy that object to normal var using angular.copy and then delete from that object and try generating table with that local variable.

Comment: How can I remove Object column value

Comment: paste your object in string in your question.

Comment: var getstock = $scope.GetOpeningStockDetailsReport;
        var OriginalStock = angular.copy(getstock); Now I want to remove sumQty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96121/discussion-between-jay-shukla-and-ramaraog).